# Magento 2 Reindex failed on customer grid

Tags: magento2, error, reindex, indexer

Magento 2 (Version 2.1.6) shows allways 2 or 3 Indexes with the processing state - and it never ends. It stays for days under processing.

After a php bin/magento indexer:reset all the indexes are out of date - which is fine I think.

But after a  php bin/magento indexer:reindex I got the fallowing message:

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>   Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Customer Grid indexer process unknown error:
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.customer_grid_flat' doesn't exist, query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_grid_flat` (
>     `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
>     `name` text NULL COMMENT 'Name' ,
>     `email` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Email' ,
>     `group_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Group_id' ,
>     `created_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Created_at' ,
>     `website_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Website_id' ,
>     `confirmation` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Confirmation' ,
>     `created_in` text NULL COMMENT 'Created_in' ,
>     `dob` date NULL COMMENT 'Dob' ,
>     `gender` int NULL COMMENT 'Gender' ,
>     `taxvat` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Taxvat' ,
>     `lock_expires` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Lock_expires' ,
>     `shipping_full` text NULL COMMENT 'Shipping_full' ,
>     `billing_full` text NULL COMMENT 'Billing_full' ,
>     `billing_firstname` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_firstname' ,
>     `billing_lastname` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_lastname' ,
>     `billing_telephone` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_telephone' ,
>     `billing_postcode` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_postcode' ,
>     `billing_country_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_country_id' ,
>     `billing_region` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_region' ,
>     `billing_street` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_street' ,
>     `billing_city` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_city' ,
>     `billing_fax` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_fax' ,
>     `billing_vat_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_vat_id' ,
>     `billing_company` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_company' ,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GROUP_ID` (`group_id`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CONFIRMATION` (`confirmation`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_DOB` (`dob`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GENDER` (`gender`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_BILLING_COUNTRY_ID` (`billing_country_id`),
>     FULLTEXT `FTI_8746F705702DD5F6D45B8C7CE7FE9F2F` (`name`, `email`, `created_in`, `taxvat`, `shipping_full`, `billing_full`, `billing_firstname`, `billing_lastname`, `billing_telephone`, `billing_postcode`, `billing_region`, `billing_city`, `billing_fax`, `billing_company`)
>   ) COMMENT='customer_grid_flat' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
>   Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
>   Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
>   Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:13
>   Search Spell-Correction index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:05
>   www-data@dicota-com:~/magento$
>   www-data@dicota-com:~/magento$
>   www-data@dicota-com:~/magento$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>   Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Customer Grid indexer process unknown error:
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.customer_grid_flat' doesn't exist, query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_grid_flat` (
>     `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
>     `name` text NULL COMMENT 'Name' ,
>     `email` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Email' ,
>     `group_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Group_id' ,
>     `created_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Created_at' ,
>     `website_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Website_id' ,
>     `confirmation` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Confirmation' ,
>     `created_in` text NULL COMMENT 'Created_in' ,
>     `dob` date NULL COMMENT 'Dob' ,
>     `gender` int NULL COMMENT 'Gender' ,
>     `taxvat` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Taxvat' ,
>     `lock_expires` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Lock_expires' ,
>     `shipping_full` text NULL COMMENT 'Shipping_full' ,
>     `billing_full` text NULL COMMENT 'Billing_full' ,
>     `billing_firstname` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_firstname' ,
>     `billing_lastname` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_lastname' ,
>     `billing_telephone` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_telephone' ,
>     `billing_postcode` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_postcode' ,
>     `billing_country_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_country_id' ,
>     `billing_region` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_region' ,
>     `billing_street` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_street' ,
>     `billing_city` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_city' ,
>     `billing_fax` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_fax' ,
>     `billing_vat_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_vat_id' ,
>     `billing_company` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_company' ,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GROUP_ID` (`group_id`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CONFIRMATION` (`confirmation`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_DOB` (`dob`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GENDER` (`gender`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_BILLING_COUNTRY_ID` (`billing_country_id`),
>     FULLTEXT `FTI_8746F705702DD5F6D45B8C7CE7FE9F2F` (`name`, `email`, `created_in`, `taxvat`, `shipping_full`, `billing_full`, `billing_firstname`, `billing_lastname`, `billing_telephone`, `billing_postcode`, `billing_region`, `billing_city`, `billing_fax`, `billing_company`)
>   ) COMMENT='customer_grid_flat' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
>   Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
>   Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
>   Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
>   Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:11
>   Search Spell-Correction index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:05
>   `

I can repeat that - the same error message. I checked the database table and we have a magento2.customer_grid_flat - so it looks ok for me.
After a few days the index goes on status READY - without any interaction from our side. But then - 2 or 3 (mostly customer grid and catalog search) indexes are again the processing state and will not be updated longer (until we kill all indexes with the reset command)

Any hints?

PHP Version:
PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Can u please drop table `customer_grid_flat` and try again?

Comment: Is it safe? Because it's a productive system. I can't do that if I lose data.

Thanks for a quick answer.

Mirko

Comment: @MirkoHufnagel were you able to figure out the fix? I having a similar issue, only in my case it is the "Product Flat Data" not re-indexing. I already tried to truncate flat catalog table, and so far no luck. On top of all, after the update I can't even add products, gets me to the 500 error page.

Comment: I strongly recommend to upgrade your M2 and PHP version as there aren't supported anymore for security and performance issues. This has been fixed in recently M2 version. Make sure your indexers are set to update by schedule too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two tables that were preventing a re-index.
The first one was orphaned (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10622738/1055492):
   customer_grid_flat
In /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mydbname, I found only a customer_grid_flat.ibd file and no customer_grid_flat.frm file.
I renamed the ibd file to ibd.old and this fixed the reindex for this table.

My second table design_config_grid_flat had both a .ibd and .frm file which I assume had become corrupted, to get this working I had to do four things (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18034693/1055492):

1. Rename both files
2. Copied the SQL that failed in the reindex and ran it it another temporary db
3. Copied the .idb and .frm file from /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/tmpdbname to /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mydbname
4. Reindexed

Disclaimer

- The Magento 2 instance in my case is a Bitnami cloud virtual machine and your mysql location may vary.
- I take no responsibility for your lost data