# Magento 2: database error customer_grid_flat doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, reindex

We could not reindex `customer_grid_flat` nor we can open Customer menu at the left side in Magento 2 admin. It gives an error. Looking around i found [this similar issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174722/magento-2-reindex-failed-on-customer-grid) Then we tried to open DB table **Customer_grid_flat** but it says table is empty. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Did you attempt the steps that user HostMyBus provided in the answer to the question you link to?  It looks like they're saying in their case the MySQL database storage files saved on the hard drive became corrupted so he made a backup of the database and loaded that into a temp db, then ran the query that failed manually on the temp db, then copied the temp db's storage files for the corrupted table back to his main DB...

Answer (score 6):

Try to execute the reindex command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I had the same problem and I didn't understand why in the admin panel instead to retrieve data from `customer_entity` table Magento use `customer_grid_flat`.
When You create an account all information are registered only in `customer_entity` but not in `customer_grid_flat`, to force the system to register the new account data in `customer_grid_flat` you must execute the reindex command or execute a cron job.
I have not yet understood why, but it is so. 
I think it's a performance issue.

Comment: Did you have to do anything else besides run the re-indexer?  The other question and answer linked to in OP's questions points to some possible file corruption in the underlying MySQL storage files and I would imagine that the reindex alone might not be able to resolve this...

PS - This is about M1 & Catalog Tables, the same principle applies to M2 & Customers - Magento uses "flat" tables to aggregate data that is split across many different subtables in their EAV model to [improve performance of read operations](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/06/10/magento-flat-tables/).

Comment: Also Index is helpful for this - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'decure_magento.catalog_product_flat_2' doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
php bin/magento i:rei customer_grid
```

If you are not able to reindex the `customer_grid`, run this instead:

```
php bin/magento i:reset customer_grid && php bin/magento i:rei customer_grid
```

then run php bin/magento indexer:reindex